# Symfony2 doctrine DQL does not replace wildcards

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to query the model from my Symfony2 project and I am not able to replace wildcards into my DQL query. Look;

```
$q2 = 
  'SELECT 
    p.codigo, 
    p.descripcion, 
    SUM(l.cantidad) as cantidad, 
    SUM(l.cantidad*l.pvp) as euros
  FROM 
    MGFAppBundle:LineaVenta l 
  JOIN 
    MGFAppBundle:Producto p 
  WITH
    l.producto = p.id
  JOIN 
    l.venta v
  WITH
    l.venta = v.id
  WHERE 
    l.producto IN (:array) 
  AND 
    v.farmacia = :farmacia 
  GROUP BY 
    p.codigo';
$query2 = $this->em->createQuery($q2)
  ->setParameter('farmacia', $farmacia)->setParameter('array', $array);
$porFarmacia = $query2->getResult();
// This does not return a single value, when it should return 2 lines.

echo $query2->getSQL();
// Returns:
// SELECT p0_.codigo AS codigo0, p0_.descripcion AS descripcion1, SUM(l1_.cantidad) AS sclr2, SUM(l1_.cantidad * l1_.pvp) AS sclr3 FROM LineaVenta l1_ INNER JOIN Producto p0_ ON (l1_.lineaventas_id = p0_.id) INNER JOIN Venta v2_ ON l1_.venta_id = v2_.id AND (l1_.venta_id = v2_.id) WHERE l1_.lineaventas_id IN (?) AND v2_.farmacia_id = ? GROUP BY p0_.codigo
```

So, question marks where parameters should be. Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be OK, I can't see any typo at first look. If you delete the **GROUP BY p.codigo** line, you get results or nothing?

Comment: This does work: $q2 = 'SELECT p.codigo, p.descripcion, SUM(l.cantidad) as cantidad, SUM(l.cantidad*l.pvp) as euros FROM MGFAppBundle:LineaVenta l JOIN MGFAppBundle:Producto p WITH l.producto = p.id JOIN l.venta v WITH l.venta = v.id WHERE l.producto IN (' . $array .') AND v.farmacia = ' . $farmacia . ' GROUP BY p.codigo';

Comment: Hummm... could the problem be at **WHERE l.producto IN (:array)** ?? Do me a favor. If you go to Debug toolbar/Doctrine, you can see the queries. What appears in the Parameters section? (for example: **Parameters: [1, true, true]** )

Comment: Nevermind. The getSQL() method returns what it should. to see the query and the parameters there's the getDQL() method, and the getParameters() method. That is what I printed on screen, and I realized that the $array did not have proper product ids, but 'codes', that are not the desired field. now everything's OK. thank you, Dani.